# How to create layer for output for LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

i'm still learning in LSTM classification.

```
my input dataset is (2386, 3) where (n_rows, n_predictive)
my output dataset is (2386, 7) where (n_rows, n_label)

my input windows size is (2369, 12, 3) where (n_sample, n_input, n_predictive)
my output windows size is (2369, 6, 7) where (n_sample, n_output, n_label)

using this code
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_input, n_predictive)))
        model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_label)))
        model.add(Activation('softmax'))
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

obtain this layer
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnnlstm_93 (CuDNNLSTM)    (None, 12, 300)           363600    
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_14 (TimeDis (None, 12, 7)             2107      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)   (None, 12, 7)             0         
=================================================================
```

and its error

```
 Error when checking target: expected activation_13 to have shape (12, 7) but got array with shape (6, 7)
```

I try to create the layer but I'm **unable to create layer with (None, 6, 7)**, do you guys have any suggestion on how I can create layer with (None, 6, 7)?

## *update*

when I try to fit the model with the same input and output windows, as below

```
input windows size is (2369, 12, 3)
output windows size is (2369, 12, 7)
```

the model does not have error BUT, I found out that the label prediction give 12 step late than the actual.

when I use different windows size for example

```
input windows size is (2369, 6, 3)
output windows size is (2369, 6, 7)
```

I found out that the label prediction give 6 step late than the actual.

I already checked windows split sequence function where I follow this code from this blog https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/

the windows split is just working fine. But it seem that the LSTM model working weird. Does the LSTM model for classification are affected with the windows size?

Comment: About the error `unable to create layer with (None, 6, 7)`. That makes sense, your model won't accept anything that has less than 12 timesteps (as you defined in the model). So you say your model gives the actual prediction after 12 steps, can you explain what this means? If that's the case, I feel there's something wrong with your data and you should look into that before changing the window size.

Comment: Does the LSTM classification layer unable to create different sequence input (3dimension) and sequence output (3dimension)? And for the prediction of the LSTM classification seem affected by the size of windows, if i use (n, 2, 3) as my input windows, the prediction will give "label0" at t+2. If i use (n,10,3) as my inputs, the prediction will give "label0" at t+10.

Comment: @lemon93, Is your issue resolved? If not, please provide the complete reproducible code so that we can help you. Thanks!